How can I get the default, standard corner radius of an NSWindow?
How can I get the default, standard corner radius of an NSWindow?
As we know, any app or window in macOS comes with a normal, standard window corner radius by default. Some apps may set custom corner radius for their windows, but I’m not looking for that. I need to know how to get the corner radius of a standard NSWindow right out of the box. I wrote code to get the corner radius, but it’s returning zero.

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var cornerRadius: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            
            Text("Corner Radius: \(cornerRadius, specifier: "%.2f")")
                .padding()
            
            Button("Read Corner Radius") {
                cornerRadius = getWindowCornerRadius() ?? 0.0
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
}

func getWindowCornerRadius() -> CGFloat? {
    
    if let window = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow {

        // I am trying to read the corner radius of the window itself, not the contentView of the NSWindow. This is the closest I’ve come to solving the issue, but I am not looking for the corner radius set by us as developers in the app. Looking to read the value set by default by Apple.

        window.contentView?.wantsLayer = true
        return window.contentView?.layer?.cornerRadius
        
    }
    return nil
}

The use case is rounding my views to match the NSWindow corner radius after removing the padding size. Look at this image—there is no harmony there. I need the window corner radius to correctly match the corner radius of the white view.


This sounds like an XY Problem. Why do you want to find this?

@Sweeper: I answered your question within my question, but the question itself is clear—there is no XY problem.

AFAIK you can’t. You need to set it yourself for both of them. Try 16 pts

There is a free app called pixie available for download from Apple developer tools. You can use it to inspect the default window corner radius.

If you look at the code in question, l am trying to read the corner radius of window itself! I am not trying to set a value.

@LeoDabus: Also, on every Mac device, macOS determines the amount of the corner radius for standard windows, so it is not a fixed value. Using third-party software to read it once won't work, as it is a dynamic value that differs from device to device. I need to read the current corner radius of an NSWindow from a Mac device.

@swiftPunk AFAIK there is no public api for that. And yes it is not a fixed value. I guess you just need to use the screen scale

@LeoDabus: Screen scale? Do you mean measuring the width and height of the Mac screen? How could that help me? Could you provide more help or share a link?

Maybe something like 8pts times uiscreen main scale.
